# Operand should contain 1 column(s) Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

[is my query okay ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUyAu.png)

```
public function parse()
{
    $db4 = $this->load->database('db4', TRUE);
    $query = $db4->query(' INSERT INTO test (nik, nama, status, bulan, tahun, hk, hb, lembur, gp, obat, transport, tunjangan, bpjs) SELECT (`karyawan`.`no_nik`, `karyawan`.`nama`, `karyawan`.`kd_status`, `absensi`.`bulan`, `absensi`.`tahun`, `absensi`.`hk`, `absensi`.`hari_besar`, `absensi`.`lembur`, `karyawan`.`gapok`, `karyawan`.`obat`, `karyawan`.`transport`, `karyawan`.`tunjangan`, `karyawan`.`bpjs`) FROM karyawan LEFT JOIN absensi ON `karyawan`.`no_nik` = `absensi`.`nik` ');
}
```

[notification of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRVID.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that issue with `karyawan.no_nik = absensi.nik` part where field `no_nik` or `nik` does not exist  cause it's talking about: **operand**

try to run this query in `phpmyadmin` or some mysql gui:

```
SELECT 
       karyawan.no_nik    AS nik,
       karyawan.nama,
       karyawan.kd_status AS status,
       absensi.bulan,
       absensi.tahun,
       absensi.hk,
       absensi.hari_besar AS hb,
       absensi.lembur,
       karyawan.gapok     AS gp,
       karyawan.obat,
       karyawan.transport,
       karyawan.tunjangan,
       karyawan.bpjs
FROM karyawan
         LEFT JOIN absensi ON (karyawan.no_nik = absensi.nik)
```

If query will be successful then scoping `SELECT` inside brackets may solve the issue:

```
public function parse()
{
    $db4 = $this->load->database('db4', TRUE);
    $query = '
      INSERT INTO test 
      (nik, nama, status, bulan, tahun, hk, hb, lembur, gp, obat, transport, tunjangan, bpjs)
      (
        SELECT karyawan.no_nik    AS nik,
               karyawan.nama,
               karyawan.kd_status AS status,
               absensi.bulan,
               absensi.tahun,
               absensi.hk,
               absensi.hari_besar AS hb,
               absensi.lembur,
               karyawan.gapok     AS gp,
               karyawan.obat,
               karyawan.transport,
               karyawan.tunjangan,
               karyawan.bpjs
        FROM karyawan
                 LEFT JOIN absensi ON (karyawan.no_nik = absensi.nik)
      )
    ';
    $query = $db4->query($query);
}
```

Comment: @ekosanto2008 what was issue? You simply pasted and it worked?

Comment: i just removed => () in SELECT  $query = $db4->query(' INSERT INTO test (nik, nama, status, bulan, tahun, hk, hb, lembur, gp, obat, transport, tunjangan, bpjs) SELECT `karyawan`.`no_nik`, `karyawan`.`nama`, `karyawan`.`kd_status`, `absensi`.`bulan`, `absensi`.`tahun`, `absensi`.`hk`, `absensi`.`hari_besar`, `absensi`.`lembur`, `karyawan`.`gapok`, `karyawan`.`obat`, `karyawan`.`transport`, `karyawan`.`tunjangan`, `karyawan`.`bpjs` FROM karyawan LEFT JOIN absensi ON `karyawan`.`no_nik` = `absensi`.`nik` ');

Comment: @ekosanto2008 seems like Your issue was with formatting. great that You solved.